# Error in Dependency Injection In angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have use providers to inject services at bootstrap like this:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,

  selector: 'sd-app',
  providers: [TokenService,  Principal, HttpClient],
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, NavbarComponent]
})
```

Still I have to use provide for HttpClient at all sub-component, My understanding  is that while injection during bootstrap singleton instance of services will be created, and while giving in providers at sub-component unique instance of service for each sub-component will be created.

**I am getting error No provider for HttpClient ! if I do not use providers for HttpClient at sub-component**
and it is specific to HttpClient

HttpClient code is:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpClient {

    constructor(private _tokenService: TokenService, private router: Router, private principal: Principal) { }
    get(url: any, headers: any) {
        //body using router, pricipal and _tokenService
    }
 }
```

Any help!

**Edit added app.component.ts**

```
  import { Component, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
  import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Routes, Router } from '@angular/router';
  import { HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';
  import { Principal } from './+login/principal';
  import { HttpClient } from './shared/http/httpclient';

  @Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'sd-app',
  providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS, Principal, HttpClient],
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
  })
  @Routes([
  {
    path: '/',
    component: SomeComponent
  }
  ])
  export class AppComponent {

    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef;
    constructor(private _principal: Principal, private _router: Router, viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
    this.viewContainerRef = viewContainerRef;
    }
  }
```

** bootstrap**

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(APP_BASE_HREF, { useValue: '<%= APP_BASE %>' })
]);
```

Comment: I feel like problem is because `HttpClient` is dependent on two other services.

Comment: please include your bootstrap file. If you have included the HTTP_PROVIDERS in root level then all the sub component will get the dependency when needed.

Comment: @Moshiour Yes I have included HTTP_PROVIDERS

Comment: please do provide your bootstrap file.

Comment: What Angular2 and Router version are you using? Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer angular and router are 2.0.0-rc.1, will try reproduce in a pluker in some time.